# Spring Data JPA entity created twice

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have written a service method `importCategories()` which retrieves a list of categories from database and recursively fills in properties and parent categories. The problem I'm experiencing is that new categories are created twice, *except* when I annotate `complete()` with `@Transactional`. Can anyone explain to me why that is? I save the child before adding it to the parent, and afterwards save the parent which has `CascadeType.ALL` on the child collection.

Model:

```
@Entity
public class Category implements Identifiable<Integer> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private Integer key;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private Category parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<Category> children = new ArrayList<Category>();

    public void add(Category category) {
        category.setParent(this);
        children.add(category);
    }

}
```

Service:

```
@Transactional
private void complete(Category category) {

    // ... (getting category info such as "name" and "parent key" from web service)

    category.setName(name);
    category = categoryRepository.saveAndFlush(category);

    if (category.getParent() == null) {

        Category parentCategory = new Category();
        parentCategory.setKey(parentKey);
        List<Category> categories = categoryRepository.findByKey(parentKey);
        if (categories.size() > 0) {
            parentCategory = categories.get(0);
        }

        parentCategory.add(category);
        parentCategory = categoryRepository.saveAndFlush(parentCategory);

        if (parentCategory.getParent() == null) {
            complete(parentCategory);
        }
    }
}

public void importCategories() {

    List<Category> list = categoryRepository.findAll();

    for (Category category : list) {
        complete(category);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a cascade ALL type then you dont need to save your child entity first, just the parent.

```
      category.getchildren().add(children)
      save(category)
```

On that moment category will save/update the entity and will do the same for children.
look another examples to understand how works the hibernate cascade: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-cascade-example-save-update-delete-and-delete-orphan/